# How do I get the length of an audio clip from a series in an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on this subtitle system. It has an array of audio clips and an array of texts. I want a single audio clip to play, get the duration of that clip, and wait for that duration. I got my code set up inside the coroutine like this:

```
 IEnumerator SubtitleCoroutine()
    {
        foreach(string subtitle in _Subtitles)
        {
            foreach(AudioClip audio in audioClips)
            {
                _Text.text=subtitle;
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(audio);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.length);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this method plays ALL the audio clips in the array and waits for their total duration to be over. How do I fix this?

Comment: You are iterating through all the audioClips for each of the subtitle strings, shouldn't you be matching them first with a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a foreach loop here, because you need to work with both arrays at the same time.

```csharp
IEnumerator SubtitleCoroutine()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < audioClips.length; i++){
        _Text.text = _Subtitles[i];
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClips[i]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audioClips[i].length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out like 20 minutes after posting, but still thanks.